# How to play streamed audio thought socketio on Android Device?

Tags: python, java, android, socket.io

I've created a simple voice call app that sends the Microphone input audio to the socket server which is written in Python and gets the audio through socket connection and plays it.
There is a problem with playing the audio on **Android device**. The sound is broken and it doesn't work correctly. I wrote a **python client** to receive the audio data and play it and it **works perfectly** with the Python client but I really don't know what is wrong with the Android code.
It is the Socket Server (Python):

```
import eventlet
from eventlet.wsgi import server as wsgi_server
from socketio import Server as SocketServer, WSGIApp


sio = SocketServer()
socket_app = WSGIApp(sio)


@sio.event
def broadcast_audio(sid, data):
    sio.emit('audio_stream', data)


wsgi_server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), socket_app)
```

And this is the Java code for the Android:

```
package dev.codewithcoffee.penpal;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Socket mSocket;
    private AudioTrack audioTrack;
    private int audioTrackOffset = 0;
    private int recordSampleRate, bufferSize;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View callView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_call, null);

        // recordSampleRate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        // bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(recordSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        recordSampleRate = 44100;
        bufferSize = 4096;

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, recordSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.play();


        initializeSocket();

        startBroadcastAudio();

        setContentView(callView);
    }

    private void initializeSocket() {
        IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
        options.forceNew = true;
        options.reconnection = true;
        options.reconnectionDelay = 2000;
        options.reconnectionDelayMax = 5000;

        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.3:5000");

           mSocket.on("audio_stream", onAudioStream);

            if (!mSocket.connected()) {
                mSocket.connect();
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private final Emitter.Listener onAudioStream = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            try {
                byte[] audioBytes = (byte[]) args[0];

                audioTrack.write(audioBytes, 0, audioBytes.length);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    private void broadcastAudio() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                recordSampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                bufferSize
        );

        // Continuously read audio data from the recorder and send it to the server
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        audioRecorder.startRecording();

        while (true) {
            int numBytesRead = audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            if (numBytesRead > 0) {
                // Send audio data to server through socket connection
                mSocket.emit("broadcast_audio", buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Run your function here
            broadcastAudio();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // This method is called on the main thread
            // You can update the UI here if needed
        }
    }

    // Call this method to start the async task
    private void startBroadcastAudio() {
        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

I tried different things to fix the android code, changing the buffer size and calc it by the existing method but it doesn't work too.